# How do I register a MSFT Oauth2 permission for e.g. SMTP AUTH when it isn't listed in AAD's resource API list

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, smtp-auth

Could anyone explain how a MSFT Oauth2 client scope with a URI of https://outlook.office.com (needed for SMTP AUTH or IMAP, for example) can be specified in a corresponding AAD permission when outlook.office.com is not listed in the resource API list ?

MSFT push Graph (which does have e.g. an SMTP AUTH permission), but they have confirmed that SMTP AUTH and IMAP are implemented only in the outlook resource API. Testing confirms this: if the client uses a scope of  https://graph.microsoft.com/SMTP.Send and an AAD Microsoft Graph permission of *SMTP.Send*, authentication fails. The acid test lies is the ‘aud’ claim in the Access token: if it is “00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000” (aka Graph) authentication fails whereas an ‘aud’ of https://outlook.office.com will succeed (other things being equal).

I would have thought naively that the client *scopes* and AAD *permissions* resource API should have the same URI.

I can’t see how granular permissions – where the AAD permissions are a superset of the client’s scopes and clients ask for the minimum they need at the time they need it – can work if I cannot specify the superset in AAD!

I have asked MSFT for enlightenment but no response.

=====

Additional tests:
If AAD Graph permissions are null and the client scope is just https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send, the access token has an ‘aud’ of https://outlook.office.com and an ‘scp’ of SMTP.Send, and authentication is OK.

But if the client scope also contains a Graph scope such as Mail.Send, ‘aud’ changes to  00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 (aka Graph) and subsequent authentication fails with ‘incorrect credentials’. I would have expected a “scope asking for one token for two different resources” type error message from the token endpoint.

And, as would be expected, if the client scope is just SMTP.Send (or https://graph.microsoft.com/SMTP.Send; the Graph URI prefix being now the default) authentication fails with ‘incorrect credentials’

These are using the V2 authorisation and token endpoints – as recommended by MSFT.

====

Further comments in response:
@Allen Wu - I cannot find IMAP.AccessAsUser.All, POP.AccessAsUser.All and SMTP.Send listed under Exchange (API permissions => + Add a permission => Request API permissions /Microsoft APIs => Exchange  or under Office 365 Exchange Online (API permissions => + Add a permission => Request API permissions / APIs my organization uses => Office 365 Exchange Online) . They are only listed under Graph. This leads to the weird situations that:

- if a client uses (e.g.) SMTP.Send  (or https://graph.microsoft.com/SMTP.Send) scope, authentication fails even though MSFT instruct (vide your last link) that the corresponding permission must be registered in Graph
- if a client uses (e.g.) https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send  scope (as instructed by MSFT), the client cannot add further https://outlook.office.com permissions (because the resource API is not listed) or use additional Graph scopes (because authentication fails and it would appear to be asking for one token to cover two APIs anyway)

Vide your comment “We see that the permissions are under Microsoft Graph in the Azure portal, but in fact the same has been added to the outlook endpoint”, MSFT could pre-empt much confusion (other StackOverflow posters have logged similar problems) if they simply listed the outlook.office.com API in AAD API permissions until Graph accessed a complete set of endpoints as well as permissions. I realise they want developers to use Graph, but the present situation is akin to being half-pregnant!

Comment: As of today (2/7/22), just as described above, the graph.microsoft.com URL (permission) STILL will not work. You must use the outlook.office.com URL. I spent DAYS trying to get that to work. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth for any future changes (hopefully)

Comment: @JohnCruz I'm facing the same problem (8/17/22). My issue is that I need to use client_credential (as I need to send/receive emails on behalf of the user in a daemon/service) and you can't use explicit scopes with that - it only supports the /.default, and for that I would need it to be available in the Azure Portal to be added to the app registration.

Comment: @Fabricio - on 30th June, MSFT announced client_credentials grant support for IMAP and POP but not SMTP. I queried this with MSFT and Steve Taylor of the Exchange team confirmed to me that this is still work in progress. So for sending, a client_credentials access token will bounce when presented to Exchange.  For receiving, IMAP.AccessAsApp and POP.AccessAsApp permissions have been added to Exchange resource ps.outlook.com, but you also need to faff around with Powershell to register the service principal to Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you just need to select the Microsoft graph permissions (SMTP AUTH or IMAP).

Currently when you need to get an access token, you can specify the `scope` as `https://outlook.office.com/{SMTP AUTH or IMAP permission}`.

I think the permissions are still in change. The Outlook permissions should be included in Microsoft Graph in the future.

Comment: Vide my 'Additional tests' comment above, my confusion persists: how do I register outlook.office.com permissions in AAD and how can a client scope have one URI but the corresponding permission have another?

Comment: @decomplexity In my mind, the permissions `IMAP.AccessAsUser.All`, `POP.AccessAsUser.All` and `SMTP.Send` are under Exchange (endpoint: `https://outlook.office365.com/`) before. And the new endpoint: `https://outlook.office.com/` begins on 2015. But this endpoint are not visible on Azure Portal -> Add a permission. See details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/use-outlook-rest-api#shutting-down-of-earlier-preview-endpoint.

Comment: @decomplexity In fact, through auth code grant flow, the permissions we add in AAD app can be different with the permissions in the authorize request. For v2.0 endpoint, we can ask for the permissions dynamically. It does not matter if you add the permissions or not in the API permissions, see details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#incremental-and-dynamic-consent. It reflects to some extent that your real permissions can be different from the permissions you define in the Azure portal.

Comment: @decomplexity The migration from outlook rest API to Microsoft Graph are still in change. We see that the permissions are under Microsoft Graph in the Azure portal, but in fact the same has been added to the outlook endpoint. I think the migration will be completed someday in the future. Currently just use this method as documented: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#configure-your-application.

Comment: please see further comments added to OP

Comment: @decomplexity Yes. the permissions are no longer under `https://outlook.office365.com/` and `https://outlook.office.com/`. They are under Microsoft Graph now. You have to use `https://graph.microsoft.com` endpoint currently. I agree that it is like half-pregnant. But I believe these permissions will be migrated to under Microsoft Graph later as I mentioned.